# Mixing `AND` and `OR` in an `IF` block in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to write the following in excel :

`if L or P > 0 and S is blank... insert "X" in col U`

To do this ive written the following, but im getting a parse error, any ideas where ive gone wrong ?

```
=IF(AND(OR(L3>0, P3>0), ISBLANK(S3)) "x", "y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma before your "x".
The logic looks correct (I'm not an excel user, so I'm not sure about the functions you're using, but logic-wise that seems fine)

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it ! Cant believe i missed that one !